# sed to replace colon with space in a file

Tags: unix, sed, cat

I have a file which has contents as

```
abd:123
gyhy:345
abgdhye:678
```

I want to replace colon with some space so that after replacement file should look like

```
abd     123
gyhy    345
abgdhye 678
```

space between string and number should be equal irrespective of string size. I tried like cat file.txt | sed 's/:/\t\t/' >> result.txt. when i see the contents with cat result.txt

```
abd     123
gyhy    345
abgdhye   678how
```

but i want contents in file like

```
abd       123
gyhy      345
abgdhye   678
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed 's/:/\t/' file` or `sed "s/:/"$'\t'"/" file`?

Comment: Space between string and number are not equal in your example output. Do you want equal space or aligned columns?

Comment: Benjamin... i need aligned columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
column -s ":" -t file
```

Output:

```
abd      123
gyhy     345
abgdhye  678
```

Comment: i modified my question what is needed.